# copying a struct with a struct member to another struct

Tags: c, struct

is the following code correct?

```
   typedef struct
   {
      int x;
      int y;
   } OTHERSTRUCT;


   struct DATATYPE
   {
      char a;
      OTHERSTRUCT b;
   }

   // ...

   // now we reserve two structs
   struct DATATYPE structA;
   struct DATATYPE structB;

   // ... probably fill insome values


   // now we copy structA to structB
   structA = structB;
```

Are both structs now completely identical? Even the "struct in the struct"?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, they are identical.

Comment: Yes, those are identical. C copies each member one after another.

Comment: Remember though that: If the `struct` contains a pointer, it is the pointer that is copied. Not the location that it points to. i.e. it is not a 'deep' copy.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

When you assign one struct variable to another, every member is copied one-by-one, including the other struct `OTHERSTRUCT` you have as a member of `DATATYPE`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, their contents is the same afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

There may well be padding bytes between `a` and `b` in `struct DATATYPE`, and these are not guaranteed to be copied by the struct assignment. That doesn't mean that they won't be, just that you can't rely on whether they are or not.

The actual members `a` and `b` will have identical values. The effect of the copy applies recursively to members of struct type, so yes the members-of-members are copied too.

Comment: Additionally, the C standard permits multiple representations of the same value (in some types). So the contents of two structs (or any object for which this is permitted) after an assignment will have the same values but might not have the same bits in memory.

Comment: @Eric: agreed, "identical values" should be understood that way. Not necessarily "identical representations" when compared via `memcmp`. In this example, on an exotic C implementation there could be padding bits in `int`, and these need not be identical after the assignment. I'm unsure whether or not assignment is allowed to change a negative zero to a zero, for ones'-complement and sign-magnitude representations. But for common-or-garden C implementations and for this struct, padding bytes are the only thing to worry about.